# How to grep two separate logs file? , currently output to only one log file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, grep

I have below command to output shell script to a file **RestartLog.log**, then to grep only "error" to another file **RestartLog_ERROR.log**.

```
 sudo  ./DailyRestart.sh |sudo tee  /RestartLog.log |grep ERROR | sudo tee /RestartLog_ERROR.log
```

I have two issues

- **Issue 1 :** I need to add another file **"RestartLog_WARNING.log"** for "warning" along with "error" , is it possible
- **Issue 2 :** Currently error out is only printing to console, i need full output to console not error output

Please help me in fixing both issues

Answer (score 1):

Only STDOUT goes through your pipes. If you need to also have STDERR, you need to first redirect it to STDOUT:

```
sudo  ./DailyRestart.sh 2>&1 | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk maybe a better option for this:

```
./DailyRestart.sh | awk '/Warning/ { print $0 >> "RestartLog_WARNING.log" } /ERROR/ { print $0 >> "RestartLog_ERROR.log" }1'
```

Search for lines containing "Warning" and print the line to the file RestartLog_WARNING.log. Search for lines containing "ERROR" and print the line to the file RestartLog_ERROR.log. Print all lines to screen with 1.